# positioning two subfigure properly

Tags: positioning, subcaption

I am trying to use subfigure

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,xcolor=dvipsnames,xcolor=table]{beamer}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                  PACKAGES
\usepackage{
  mathrsfs, amsmath,    amsfonts,   amssymb,    makeidx,
  graphics, textpos,    color,      everysel,   amsthm,
  epigraph, enumerate,  mathrsfs,   bm,     amssymb,
  amsbsy,   mathtools,  graphicx,   sidecap,    color,
  tikz,     pgf,        xxcolor,    subcaption
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{two subfig}
  \begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{subfigure}[h]{.6\textwidth}
      \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=.250]{images/graph.png}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.15\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[scale=.2]{images/arrow.png}
    \end{subfigure}
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

where two graph is in one png file `graph.png` and blue arrow over the grey balls is `arrow.png`

As you can see, the two picture are overlapping over one another, though there is a lot of space on left. Any idea what can be done so that they are placed in a better way?

[image: two subfig]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

place a `\hfill` command between the two subfigures.